# Websocket python cannot send message

Tags: python, web, websocket

I am trying to use websocket to retrieve data displayed on a web page from a local device.
I thought it would be simple as I would simply need to copy the informations displayed on the dev tools, however it is still not working.

One of the issue I encounter, is that I don't know in which format my message need to be sent. On the dev tools, this is the message sent (base64):

```
g6ZoZWFkZXKDpHR5cGWsRnVuY3Rpb25DYWxsqGNsaWVudElkzc3sqGZ1bmN0aW9us1ZpZXcvUHJlc2VudC9jcmVhdGWkZGF0YcCnb3B0aW9uc8A=
```

There is also the UTF-8 format, I tried both, but it still didn't end up working.

Basically, I can send the message, but then there is no response, where on the dev tools, I can clearly see the data coming in.

Here is my code:

```
headers = json.dumps({
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
'Connection': 'Upgrade',
'Host': '192.168.1.2',
'Origin': 'http://192.168.1.2',
'Pragma': 'no-cache',
'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits',
'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'ASZXwfzA60WlSRhPPlvngw==',
'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13',
'Upgrade': 'websocket',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'})

ws = create_connection('ws://192.168.1.2/crownMSGPACK',headers=headers)
to_send = '¦header¤type¬FunctionCall¨clientIdÍÅ¨function³View/Present/create¤dataÀ§optionsÀ'
ws.send(to_send)
message = ws.recv()
print(f"Received: {message}")
```